# Why close and not migrate off-topic question?

Tags: discussion, scope, migration, specific-question

Just came across [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27241/what-is-this-startoptions). It has been closed as off-topic. While I agree that it's surely off-topic, what I’d like to know is why was it closed and not migrated to Stack Overflow? They could handle it.

Just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Migration is really for outstanding questions that happen to be in the wrong place.

While that question isn't the worst I've ever seen, migration should be the exception rather than the rule.

Answer (score 3):

It wasn't migrated because it would create a duplicate (to the nth degree).

Unfortunately I didn't have time to find the best Stack Overflow question to add as a link in the comments.